# Is There anyway to solve webpack error in prisma

Tags: javascript, prisma, react-typescript

view.js:17 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'path'

```
at ./node_modules/express/lib/view.js (view.js:17:1)

at  (hot module replacement:62:1)
at ./node_modules/express/lib/application.js (application.js:22:1)
at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
at ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js (express.js:18:1)
```

Comment: When exactly are you getting this error?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.